# Extracting list from a list of lists obtained using Solve function

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

After solving a set of equations I got a solution like the following using `Solve[]` function.

```
{{X0 -> 0,X1 -> 0, Xn1 -> 0, X2 -> 0, 
  Xn2 -> 0}, {X0 -> -0.046557 + 0.0660528 I, 
  X1 -> -0.00129788 - 0.104325 I, Xn1 -> -0.0370385 - 0.0938482 I, 
  X2 -> -0.00857655 + 0.0700392 I, 
  Xn2 -> 0.0466159 + 0.0600041 I}, {X0 -> 0.046557 - 0.0660528 I, 
  X1 -> -0.00129788 - 0.104325 I, Xn1 -> -0.0370385 - 0.0938482 I, 
  X2 -> 0.00857655 - 0.0700392 I, 
  Xn2 -> -0.0466159 - 0.0600041 I}, {X0 -> -0.094816 + 0.182855 I, 
  X1 -> 0, Xn1 -> 0, X2 -> 0, Xn2 -> 0}, {X0 -> 0.094816 - 0.182855 I,
   X1 -> 0, Xn1 -> 0, X2 -> 0, Xn2 -> 0}, {X0 -> 0, 
  X1 -> 0.109897 - 0.273052 I, Xn1 -> 0.0246269 - 0.3725 I, X2 -> 0, 
  Xn2 -> 0}, {X0 -> 0, X1 -> 0.109897 - 0.273052 I, 
  Xn1 -> 0.0246269 - 0.3725 I, X2 -> 0, Xn2 -> 0}}
```

My intend is to extract only those solutions from the result where the condition `Im(X0)!=0&&Im(X1)!=0&&Im(Xn1)!=0&&Im(X2)!=0&&Im(Xn2)!=0` is met, i.e., the second and third solutions in this case.

Comment: I am sorry. It should be `!= 0`. I have corrected it now.

Comment: The expression passed as the first argument to [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) can be a system of equations or **inequalities** for the variables. Include the inequalities in your `Solve` and the solution should satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pick[solution, 
   And @@ Thread[Im[{X0, X1, Xn1, X2, Xn2}] != 0] /. solution]
```

> {{X0 -> -0.046557 + 0.0660528 I, X1 -> -0.00129788 - 0.104325 I, 
>     Xn1 -> -0.0370385 - 0.0938482 I, X2 -> -0.00857655 + 0.0700392 I, 
>     Xn2 -> 0.0466159 + 0.0600041 I},
>   {X0 -> 0.046557 - 0.0660528 I, 
>     X1 -> -0.00129788 - 0.104325 I, Xn1 -> -0.0370385 - 0.0938482 I, 
>     X2 -> 0.00857655 - 0.0700392 I, Xn2 -> -0.0466159 - 0.0600041 I}}

Comment: Initial version of my question had a mistake. The condition should be `Im(X0)!=0&&Im(X1)!=0&&Im(Xn1)!=0&&Im(X2)!=0&&Im(Xn2)!=0`. I have corrected it now. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has worked.